# Are there any wifi micro sd card

Tags: wifi, wireless, ip-camera, microsd

Are there any micro sd cards that are wifi so they can send data without wires?

Comment: Something like: https://www.amazon.com/wifi-sd-card/s?k=wifi+sd+card ?

Answer (score 2):

Nope, SD (and MicroSD) use a few pins (9 if i'm correct) to get power and transfer data. Those power pins cannot be made wireless because of space constraints, and the data pins can maybe made wireless in SD cards (not that you want to do that), but again, not MicroSD because of space constraints

Comment: And, as it would need an external power source, what would be the point anyway? May as well plug it in a computer.